# Joining 3 tables with Conditional Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am figuring out how to find Order extensions rate for a user for the data below. All orders are in Order table and all Orderitems are stored in RentalItems. An order can contain 1 or more Items. If a User Extends Any 1 Item, this means the order is Extended. So I want to find out the Order Extension Rate of a user by checking **Total OrderExtensionsByUser/TotalOrdersPlacedByUser**

**User Table**: UserID, fname, LName, Position,

**Order Table**: User 7 placed 2 orders and User 3 placed 3 Orders

| OrderID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |

**RentalItems**:

| RentalItemID | OrderID | ItemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 9 |
| 6 | 3 | 7 |
| 7 | 4 | 11 |
| 8 | 5 | 12 |

**RentalExtions**: Both Order 1&2 have been extended since one more or more than 1 items in that order have been extended

| RentalItemID | ExtensionBy_UserID | ExtDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 2020-07-20 |
| 2 | 7 | 2020-03-05 |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-03-05 |
| 8 | 3 | 2020-03-05 |

So in this case, For user 7 and 3, it should be,

**TotalOrderExtensionsByUser/AllOrdersPlacedByUser**:

1. userID 7: 1/2= 0.50
2. userID 3: 2/3= 0.66

**Desired output** ( for all users, not for particular user )

| userID | fname | Lname | ExtRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | jon | smith | 0.50 |
| 3 | smith | tucker | 0.66 |

Any possible way to do this?

The code I had working before, Which was also given by a user on stackOverflow, was below. But I realized it only checks for extension rate by user within ExtensionTable. But in reality, what I am looking for is different.

This code will look within RentalExtensions and give me output as 2/4=0.40 for user 3. But what I need is different AS I Explained Above.

```
select UserID, fname,  lname, JobTitle,
    (select avg(case when re.ExtensionBy_UserID = r.userId then 1.0 else 0 end)
      from RentalExtensions re
      cross apply (values (userId) ) r(userId)
     ) as ExtensionRate from [user]
where userID in (select distinct ExtensionBy_UserID from RentalExtensions) and JobTitle = 'Support Staff'
```

**Edit 1:**

- Now that I think of it, I don't technically need `ExtentendedBy_UserID` since it will be the same person extending the Order.

Comment: Hello @Dale K.. The Query I though I had working was incorrect. It only looked at Average of user within RentalExtension Table. but I will Post it, hang on

Comment: hmm.. I was just thinking if another user extends the order. But let me remove it, and check, maybe it will make things easier for simplicity.

Comment: sorry for delay.. I just edited post with query

Comment: for user 3, the code will do 2/4=0.50 Within Extension Table. But What I need is different as I explained above

Comment: @NebelzCheez Please check my code and let me know does it resolve your problem or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work... if you provide the DDL+DML I'll test it for you.

```
select U.UserId, convert(decimal(9,2),sum(HasExtension) / count(*))
from (
  select OrderId, UserId
    -- To ensure the sum is decimal not int
    , convert(decimal(9,2),case when exists (select 1 from RentalExtions E where E.RentalItemId in (select RI.RentalItemId from RentalItem RI where RI.OrderId = O.OrderId)) then 1 else 0 end) HasExtension
  from [Order] O
) O
inner join [User] U on U.UserId = O.UserId
group by U.UserId;
```

I strongly encourage you to provide sample data as DDL+DML in all future questions as that makes it much easier for us to answer.

Comment: Thank you, Give me a few mins, let me Check against my data

Comment: Im still checking Dale, sorry for the delay, I'm just testing all the possible scenarios with my Data... but so far it seems to work...just a few more mins!

Comment: ITS WORKING!!!! thank you so much man. By DDL+DML do you mean the code to create the table and its data ? I will keep in mind for future

Comment: Yes DDL+DML is the create table, insert into table. I just use table variables, but you can use temp tables. You'll find in setting up such a [mre] that you understand the problem better yourself and in some instances will solve it before posting.

Comment: I doubt that 'convert(decimal(9,2),sum(HasExtension) / count(*))' will give '0.00' for both user 3 and 7 because you converted to decimal after the division. The safe way could be 'convert(decimal(9,2), sum(HasExtension) / convert(decimal(9,2), count(*))'

Comment: @GenWan sure does, because `HasExtension` is already `decimal(9,2)`, so in fact the calculation ends up with 4 decimal places, which is why I truncate it back to 2.